# Asn to text file convertor in java

Tags: java, asn.1

I have to fetch file from ftp server, file format is of binary `asn` type.
I need them to convert in text file, and parse the relevant data.
I am using jdk1.7. I can also use third party jar but it should be license free.
If someone give me an example, it would be better.

Answer (score 0):

I would like to suggest you using: http://www.bouncycastle.org/java.html

After fetching from ftp server, for a quick check use `org.bouncycastle.asn1.util.ASN1Dump` class:

```
ASN1InputStream stream = new ASN1InputStream(new ByteArrayInputStream(data));
ASN1Primitive object = stream.readObject();
System.out.println(ASN1Dump.dumpAsString(object));
```

This will print the structure of your file.

If you know the structure of your file you gonna need to use a parser like:

```
ASN1InputStream stream = new ASN1InputStream(new ByteArrayInputStream(data));
DERApplicationSpecific application = (DERApplicationSpecific) stream.readObject();
ASN1Sequence sequence = (ASN1Sequence) application.getObject(BERTags.SEQUENCE);
Enumeration enum = sequence.getObjects();
while (enum.hasMoreElements()) {
    ASN1Primitive object = (ASN1Primitive) secEnum.nextElement();
    System.out.println(object);
}
```

By the way, `ASN1Primitive` is a base ASN.1 object from a byte stream. It has a plenty of types (http://www.borelly.net/cb/docs/javaBC-1.4.8/prov/org/bouncycastle/asn1/ASN1Primitive.html) that you can inherit to and get right type.

Comment: what is ASN1Primitive here and i am not getting the octet string. can you please tell me how to print the octet string?

Comment: In this scenario you will see the whole content of a file.

Comment: But instead of value of octet string it is coming like DER Octet String[1] .... i want it something like that DER Octet String[WE234]